# Probability problem

Tags: probability

**Problem: A batch of pieces of gold contains 3% defective pieces. you withdraw 10 pieces from the batch without replacement. Find the probability to get at least 1 defective piece.**

---

My try :

$P(A) = 1 - P(\overline{A})$ where $\overline{A}$ : "getting no defective pieces"

I'm  having a hard time trying to visualize what's $P(\overline{A})$ here I would say $P(\overline{A}) = .97^{10}$ but my intuition tells me that I'm wrong.

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: The only way I can think of, is to assume the overall amount to be x and I think the answer depends on the size of batch, i.e. of x

Comment: Are you sure it says _without_ replacement? If so, I think you need to be told how many pieces you have in the batch.

Comment: @quallenjäger Thanks for the catch earlier.

Comment: @Max You are welcome. I am working on this thread too, but I don't see any approach with the information so far given.

Comment: If the problem statement is correct, we may have to assume the batch is large enough so that the probability remains constant even after each piece is drawn.